# ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterUpgradeableReadLock(0) is blocking

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, locking, readerwriterlockslim

In my .Net application, I've a place where I declare a `ReaderWriterLockSlim`:

```
    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim m_lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim(LockRecursionPolicy.SupportsRecursion);
```

At some other place, I refresh some value every 100ms, so basically if one time, the lock isn't accessible, this isn't a big deal, I just want to exit and wait for the next call.

So I've the following method's content:

```
if (m_lock.TryEnterUpgradeableReadLock(0)){
   ..
}
```

In the application, I'm currently having a deadlocks(which seems to have nothing to do with this current issue), so I paused my application to check the threads and I saw that I've more than 20 threads that are currently blocked on the if condition.

This is very weird, because [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb355755(v=vs.100).aspx) is very clear about this:

> If millisecondsTimeout is 0 (zero), this method checks the lock state
>   and returns false immediately if the desired state is unavailable.

The question is simple. **WHYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY?** I tried to put breakpoints after the `TryEnterUpgradeable`, to just continue, but this doesn't work.

Comment: Assuming there's something wrong with ReaderWriterLockSlim never gets you very far.  The 99.9% case is that there's something wrong with the code that uses it.  You didn't post nearly enough of it, what happens when it returns *false* matters a great deal.

Comment: I don't assume anything(if it was the case I would not have come here). If it returns null, nothing happens. This "if" is the only code called in a Timer event. But I'm trying to understand what could be the reason it doesn't exit from this method(this is a fact, when I pause, I've one thread which is using this lock, and thoses 20 threads waiting on this.

What happens if the one having the lock is in a read lock, and this one is in an upgradeable read lock. Does it still exit directly?

Comment: One more thing, this happens ONLY if I've Visual Studio attached to the exe. If not, everything is working fine

Comment: _"The question is simple"_ -- simple to state, perhaps. But impossible to answer if you fail to provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: I second Peter's comment.  Are you able to reproduce this problem in a very small minimal program?  If so, please post that.  Otherwise, your post will only help you to vent, but not to get solutions. :)

Comment: Also, just a thought.  But can you go in VS, under the Debug menu, and make sure to delete ***all*** breakpoints?

Comment: I don't even manage to reproduce this while not starting it in visual Studio. I was hoping to find someone who had the same kind of issue. I will try to make a minimal example, but I'm not very confident. This happens when having a lot of disk access, and communication (remoting) which access in read this lock

Comment: Can you please show more code? Not necessary minimal code sample. Because it's definitely unclear what exactly happen.